# Clients need to delete cookies most of the times in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, web-deployment

I am having my mvc project that is working fine on my local machine.  However, once posted on the server, the users can`t access the login the secong time they are trying to access the website.  They have to delete the cookies.  Why is that so? How can I correct that?

Global.asax.cs

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
 args.user = new MyProject.Web.UI.Classes.UserPrincipal(GetUserFromCache(ticket.Name))
```

SourceFile: c:\Myproject\Code\MvcUI\Global.asax.cs

```
    public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
        {
            if (null != Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName])
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
                args.User = new MyProject.Web.UI.Classes.UserPrincipal(GetUserFromCache(ticket.Name));
            }
        }
        else
            throw new HttpException("Cookieless Forms Authentication is not supported for this application.");
    }

    public void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
    {
        string username = args.Identity.Name.Substring(args.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
        Myproject.API.User user = GetUserFromCache(username);

        if (null == user)
            throw new HttpException("User could not be found.");

        args.User = new MyProject.Web.UI.Classes.UserPrincipal(user);
    }
```

AccountController

```
[HttpPost]
        public bool LogOn(string userName, string password, string returnUrl, bool rememberMe = false)
        {
            MyProject.API.User user = MyProject.API.User.Load(userName);
            string errorMessage = "Your user name and/or password is incorrect.";
            if (null != user && user.IsValidPassword(password))
            {
                user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                user.Save();
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
                return true;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception(errorMessage);
        }
```

web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="nhibernate" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="MvcUI.HtmlHelpers" />
                <add namespace="MyProject.API" />
                <add namespace="MvcUI.Models" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>


    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
            <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            </buildProviders>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

    <nhibernate>
        <add key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
        <add key="hibernate.dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect"/>
        <add key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
        <add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string" value="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDatabase;User=me;Pwd=password;"/>
        <add key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </nhibernate>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

account Model

```
    public interface IFormsAuthenticationService
{
    void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie);
    void SignOut();
}

public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthenticationService
{
    public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
}
```

The error message points to the Gloabal.asax.cs file and shown above.
Error message:
[image]
[image]

---

I have also included a machine key generated but it has not solved the problem,

Comment: Your website is running on iis6/7?

Comment: tested on both iis6 and 7.  Same on both

Comment: can u post more code which will give us process flow context ?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without context and some real code.

Comment: @Darin, what information you need exactly, I can post them?

Comment: @learning, how does your exact code for authenticating users look like? In what part of the application is it written? How does the cookie creation process look like? How does the cookie reading, parsing and decryption code look like? How does a Fiddler dump of the network traffic look like between the local machine and the remote server look like?

Comment: @Darin, please find code in the above.  Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Are you mixing both Windows and Forms authentication in your site? How are those `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` and `WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` called? How does your web.config look like? How is your web server configured for this scenario?

Comment: @Darin, please find web.config as above

Comment: What do you mean with "the users can`t access the login the secong time they are trying to access the website"? Are they redirected to somewhere else upon accessing the login page for the second time? Or? Please see my answer below.

Comment: @Efran They are having the error message as shown above and in the Global.asax.cs part code above.

Comment: Thanks, @learning. I've added a new answer that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you for having tried to reply to the question.  Indeed they were all helpful.  I solved the problem myself by adding a machinekey to the wenconfig, as well as a form name had to be there.  without te form name, even the machine key was not useful

Answer (score 2):

Based on your feedback, the reason you are experiencing that error may be due to the fact you are using an auto-generated [machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx) for your application (also possibly in multiple machines/app pools or even in one app pool that recycles too frequently).

Please make sure to check [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx) out.

Comment: @sra: This is a totally different answer, I didn't update my first post because it may actually help someone else having similar problems.

Comment: I had this same issue (with a different exception) when using `Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.  The cookie's encryption/decryption process was based on the machine key, so when changing servers, the cookie could not be decrypted.  A simple machine key in the `web.config` file did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you applied [this patch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-070)?

I see you don't have `ticketCompatibilityMode` set as .net 4 has changed the way encryption works.

```
<forms 
    loginUrl="/Login.aspx" 
    timeout="2880" 
    ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework20"
    domain="domain.com"/>
```

Check that you have the same machineKeys on both systems. Make sure you also apply that [patch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-070).

*Because the patch modifies the encryption/signing behavior of certain features in ASP.NET, it is important that you apply it to all machines in a web-farm.  If you have a mix-match of patched/un-patched systems you’ll have forms-authentication, webresource.axd, and scriptresource.axd requests succeed/fail depending on which server they hit in the farm (since the encryption used would be different across them).*

Answer (score 0):

I assume your users are redirected to somewhere upon reaching the login page if the request is authenticated and *thus* they can't access the login page after the first successful login.

If this is the case, you may want to force your users to sign out upon reaching the login page, on the first load of the page. For example (Razor syntax, C#):

```
@if (!IsPost && Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

Comment: I am not able to reach the login form at all

Answer (score 0):

On the GET (not post) of LogOn action method.  Check if user is authenticated and log out if so.

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
     FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```